# R - setting assessment criteria for regsubsets in leaps package

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to perform a regression using best-subset selection.

As an example here is the equivalent to what I'm doing based on the ChickWeight data from the datasets package.

```
leaps_test <- regsubsets(weight~Time+Diet,data=ChickWeight,nbest=1)
```

I would however like to be able to control how the "best subset" assessment is made by using the residual sum of squares (RSS). If that is how regsubsets works by default I'd still like to know how to change this criteria in-case I ever want to assessment to be made based on information criteria.

Answer (score 2):

The question and answer are two year old. But i think it's still useful to answer for someone, who are searching this information. I want to answer as comment but dont have enough reputation.

This answers the question of bibzzz (as comment to Davide Passaretti answer), if there is a way two use a criterion other than R2 for plot: With the argument `scale = c("Cp", "adjr2", "r2", "bic")` in the function `plot(regsubsets.obj, scale = ...)` you can choose which criteria you want.

The four are the most popular criteria. Maybe you want AIC. But you dont need it because Cp and AIC give you the same result, which means the model with the smallest Cp has the smallest AIC too.

Answer (score 1):

`?regsubsets.default` Since this function returns separate best models of all sizes up to nvmax and since different model selection criteria such as AIC, BIC, CIC, DIC, ... differ only in how models of different sizes are compared, the results do not depend on the choice of cost-complexity tradeoff.

However, if you want to visually inspect different associated criteria, you can specify a different scale in the plot command.

`?plot.regsubsets`

plot(x, labels=obj$xnames, main=NULL, scale=c("bic", "Cp", "adjr2", "r2"), col=gray(seq(0, 0.9, length = 10)),...)

Answer (score 0):

From `?regsubsets.default`:

Since this function returns separate best models of all sizes up to nvmax and since different model selection criteria such as AIC, BIC, CIC, DIC, ... differ only in how models of different sizes are compared, the results do not depend on the choice of cost-complexity tradeoff.

Comment: However I can rank the competing models by R2 for example using plot(leaps_test ,scale="r2"). Is there a way that I can use a measure other than r2 for this plot?